# Fail To Connect Qml signal to C++ Slot

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I have been trying to connect signal between Qml file and c++, but public slot in c++ doesn't seem to receive the signal.
What might be wrong with my program?

**main.qml**

```
Item{
    id:item
    signal qml_signal
    Button{
        onClicked: {
            item.qml_signal();
        }
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
QQuickView view(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
QObject *item = view.rootObject();
Myclass myclass;
QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(qml_signal()), &myclass,SLOT(cppSlot()));
```

**myclass.h**

```
void cppSlot() ;
```

**myclass.cpp**

```
void Myclass::cppSlot(){
    qDebug() << "Called the C++ slot with message:";
}
```

Comment: There could possibly be many reasons .. depending on your code, please share [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Who knows what's wrong with your code since I can not see it. Maybe a fortune-teller can help you, provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want objects to interact between C++ and QML, you must do it on the QML side, since obtaining a QML object from C++ can cause you many problems, as in this case, the signal created in QML can not be handled in C++.

The solution is to export your object `myclass` to QML and make the connection there:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "myclass.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    Myclass myclass;
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myclass", &myclass);

    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Item{
    id:item
    signal qml_signal
    Button{
        onClicked: item.qml_signal()
    }
    onQml_signal: myclass.cppSlot()
}
```

Comment: @eyllanesc: Though I support your opinion, on where the connection shall be made - for me it works fine, when you establish it on the C++ side. I guess there is another error in the incomplete, non-verifiable example of the OP